# Errors when upgrading to Android SDK 28

Tags: android

My app currently works with `targetSdkVersion 25`. When I change it to 28, I also have to update all of my support libraries to 28.0.0. To avoid conflicts with the support libraries used by my other dependencies, I add the following two lines to all of my dependencies that also have some type of support library dependence:

```
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
```

When I do that I get a “package android.support.v7.app does not exist”
 error, and numerous other (mostly Glide) missing package errors.

How can I smoothly upgrade to SDK 28?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should migrate to AndroidX. Read here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: So are support libraries no longer a thing?

Comment: Google switched to AndroidX, current support libraries won't be updated any longer. AndroidX is pretty much the same now, but they changed namespaces and versioning

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! Thank you for making my upgrade to the latest supported tools as smooth as possible. I've been struggling to move to v28 for a while now!